# swift - add subview to segment control causes invalid behavior

Tags: ios, swift, controls, badge, segment

i have a segment control

```
let mySegmentControl = UISegmentedControl()
```

i add two titles for it

```
mySegmentControl.setTitle(title: "one", forSegmentAt: 0)
mySegmentControl.setTitle(title: "two", forSegmentAt: 1)
```

i add a label badge to "one"

```
let myBagdeLabel = UILable(badgeText: "0")
mySegmentControl.addSubView(myBagdeLabel)
```

the issue is: when "one" is seleted the myBagdeLabel is displayed behind the background color. i did search but did not see any code to fix this issue. see my pictures.[image]

Answer (score 0):

try `mySegmentControl.bringSubview(toFront: myBadgeLabel)`

Comment: did try and this did not work

    mySegmentControl.addSubView(myBagdeLabel)

brings myBagdeLabel to the top already